# Converse of Intermediate Value Theorem with additional assumptions

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the following partial converse of the Intermediate Value Theorem:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ maps any closed interval to a closed interval and such that the pre-image of any singleton $\{x\}$ is closed. Then $f$ is continuous.

---

A brief outline of my proof:

-Suppose $f$ is discontinuous at $a$, i.e:

$\exists \delta >0:\forall \epsilon>0 \exists x:|x-a|<\epsilon,|f(x)-f(a)| \ge\delta$

-We may WLOG assume that $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists x:|x-a|<\epsilon,f(x)\ge f(a)+\delta$

-Since $f([a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon])$ is an interval containing $f(a)$ and some $f(x) \ge f(a)+\delta$, it must contain $f(a)+\delta$.

-Hence we can find a sequence $x_n$ which has limit $a$ and for which $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(x_n)=f(a)+\delta$.

-Since $f^{-1}(f(a)+\delta)$ is closed, it must contain the limit point $a$, which implies $\delta=0$, a contradiction.

---

The proof looks good to me except that I have never used the assumption that $f$ maps closed intervals to **closed** intervals.

So my question is, is there a flaw in the proof or is this assumption unnecessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be one fairly small oversight in your argument, depending on just what the WLOG hides. [**Added:** It turns out that it hides a valid argument; see the comments below.] You can’t guarantee that there’s an $x\in[a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon]$ such that $f(x)>f(a)+\delta$: you can guarantee only that there is an $x\in[a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon]$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|\ge\delta$, i.e., either $f(x)\ge f(a)+\delta$ or $f(x)\le f(a)-\delta$. Then you can use the interval-preserving property of $f$ to conclude that for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is an $x_n$ such that $|x_n-a|<\frac1n$ and $f(x_n)\in\{f(a)-\delta,f(a)+\delta\}$. Then, finally, there must be a subsequence $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ on which $f$ is constant, either at $f(a)-\delta$ or at $f(a)+\delta$. Whichever it is, the rest of your argument still goes through.

The argument requires only that $f$ map closed intervals to intervals. Of course since $f$ then turns out to be continuous, we can conclude that in fact it must map bounded closed intervals to closed intervals.

Comment: my reasoning was as follows: consider the following two statements: (I) $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists x:|x-a|<\epsilon,f(x) \ge f(a)+\delta$, (II)$\forall \epsilon>0 \exists x:|x-a|<\epsilon,f(x) \le f(a)-\delta$. I claim that at least one of (I) and (II) must be true (and hence we may wlog assume (I) is true, as I did in my proof). If they are both false, then $\exists \epsilon_1>0: \forall x, |x-a|<\epsilon_1 \to f(x) < f(a)+\delta$ and similarly $\exists \epsilon_2>0: \forall x, |x-a|<\epsilon_2 \to f(x) < f(a)-\delta$.

Comment: Hence  $ \forall x, |x-a|<\min\{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\} \to |f(x)-f(a)|<\delta$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Joshua: Fair enough: but that’s enough work that you really ought to include enough of it to justify the WLOG (or else do what I did and postpone it to a later point in the argument). I really couldn’t tell from what you’d written whether you’d made a genuine oversight or were skipping an argument like the one that you just made.

Comment: OK. I thought it was obvious since its just negating all the quantifiers. In any case, thanks for your help. I still feel a bit uneasy though because I am slightly surprised that the problem statement included an unnecessary assumption.

Comment: @Joshua: You’re doing a little more than just negating all of the quantifiers — not a lot, I admit, but some. And I was reading as I’d read a homework assignment in an undergraduate real analysis class; in that context I always wanted to see enough to convince me that the student understood the argument completely. \\ As far as the hypothesis goes, all that’s really needed, in fact, is that $f$ take order-convex sets to order-convex sets. \\ You’re welcome.